# Delphi 7 under Windows 10

Tags: encoding, windows-10, delphi-7, arabic, character-set

I am talking about Design not Runtime.
Is there a way to fix the Encoding and Character Sets issues? Example of messed up form title in Arabic below. Some French letters such as é show up like this too.

[image]

Update: Components stored in the DFM like this 
    Caption = #1575#1604#1593#1585#1576

are not affected (whether it's windows 7 or 10) and are displayed properly.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to use a tool that supports international characters

Comment: Such tools like Lazarus are slower and generate heavy and slow code. Also, this behavior is not present in Windows 7.

Comment: I thini fpc is a better compiler than d7 but in any case I was thinking of modern delphi

Comment: Delphi 7 doesn't support Unicode (mostly).  All of the Win32 APIs it uses under the hood are ANSI-based only. And Arabic doesn't play nice with ANSI. You can only use characters that are present in the user's ANSI locale at the OS layer. Otherwise, you would have to ditch the VCL (or at least hook into it) and use the Unicode-based Win32 APIs directly instead.

Comment: I have tons of work-arounds, like you stated: ditching the VCL works. TNT Components help. But now I think I understand why Windows 10 now. Thanks.

Comment: Please [*do not* use (sole) images of code/data/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3439404) in your [mcve].
Copy the actual text, paste it into the question, then format it as code.  Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Thank you for the comment but that's pretty much it.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem by using TNT Components and writing a program that converts the strings in my DFM files using ord like this

```
 object l1: TLabel
      Left = 735
      Top = 0
      Width = 32
      Height = 33
      Align = alRight
      Alignment = taRightJustify
      Caption = #1575#1604#1593#1605#16
```

Delphi 7 doesn't support unicode. Delphi 2009 does. Delphi 2010 is the closest in feel to Delphi 7.

Answer (score -2):

I use Hyper-V virtual machine with Windows 7 for that...

Comment: But the program will still have those issues when ran on Windows 10.